# Finishing technique for gaps between the wall and the live wood we installed that shrunk

Tags: wood

[image] We installed a large slab of wood and it has shrunk away from the wall.

Comment: If it's winter where you are now, wait for summer. If the slab was not dry and dried out, you may have *some* amount of "now it's dry and smaller" and *some* amount of "seasonal movement with moisture changes in the house" - if you fill it at "seasonal minimum" things may get messy at "seasonal maximum." The other usual option is trim molding to hide the gap and allow it to move without "filling" anything. No need to wait if doing that.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - for flooring yes but for this I would do it in the winter.  Drywall might lose to a good wood filler and I would want to fill it at the biggest gap.   You fill it in the summer you know you have a slight crack in the winter and on what side will the crack be?    For something this small I would risk it,  if it holds to July you may have a permanent worry free fix.   I have used Durhams plus latex stain on a number of things and you could match this wood pretty easy as it is a little darker.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - mcgyver carpenter might add a layer of mud all the way up or at least most of the way up and naturally cover the gap with extra wall.   I have done this before, maybe not at this scale.

Comment: Ok so happy to get your comments. I like the idea of calking with the wood color. Is it also suggested that I clean up the wood edges so the eye doesn’t go there. I’m worried about not matching the stain again of I file and sand the edge before I calk.

Answer (score 1):

Most common solution would simply be caulk with a color matching the wood, not the wall.

Any sanding or harsh chemicals will damage the existing finish.

If you can apply without masking, you avoid risk of peeling off either finish. Choose a product for water cleanup if you doubt your skill.

Apply sparingly usually works best, you want people's eyes to ignore the gap not see a bold stripe of dissimilar material. Sometimes slightly recessing the caulking works well to trick the eye into seeing less depth. Start their and use it as backer if you need to bring it flush with the surface.

Backer rod helps in many significant ways, but carpenters usually omit.

Touch up those ends before you caulk, the unfinished wood draws attention.

Comment: Ok so happy to get your comments. I like the idea of calking with the wood color. Is it also suggested that I clean up the wood edges so the eye doesn’t go there. I’m worried about not matching the stain again of I file and sand the edge before I calk. –

Answer (score 0):

Buy Durhams and mix it with latex stain, install and sand.

You will have to do a lot of testing to get the color match to be right.